# Holiday program error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was asked to make a program that takes the day that I start my travel length of my stay as an input and give the day that I return in as an output so I tried this and I keep getting an error that says (KeyError = -3)

Note: I'm a beginner, so be easy on me :)

```
dect = {0:'Sunday', 1: 'Monday', 2:'Tuesday',3:'Wednesday', 4:'Thursday',
     5:'Friday',6:'Saturday'
              }

def day(x):
    print( dect[x])

def holiday(start,length):
    length = length + start
    while True:
        if length <= 0:
            break
            print(length)
        else:
            length = length - 7    
    day(length)

s = int(input('Enter the start day: '))
l = int(input('Enter the length of your stay: '))
holiday(s,l)
```

Comment: `else: length = length - 7`. What if your length is 2 and your start is 2? What would `length` end up as?

Comment: I guess the purpose of this assignment is to learn the modulo operator (`%`). See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations for details.

Comment: Try : `if length < 7:`

Answer (score 4):

The value of `length` can become negative and this is why you're looking up `-3` in the dictionary.

For example, if my holiday is 4 days (`length = 4`) then you're doing `length = length - 7` which means you're calling `day()` with `-3` as value.

Your dictionary only has values for the keys 0 - 6 and that's why you're getting a `KeyError` as the key `-3` is not in the dictionary.

You can fix it by changing the check into `if length < 7`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, simply use datetime module.

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
d = date.today() + timedelta(days=2)
print d
```

You can use timedelta to add as many days/hours/whatever you want.  [See here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your holiday function as -

```
def holiday(start,length):
    length = length + start
    length = length % 7
    day(length)
```